# Mysql Insert query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im getting an sql syntax error somewhere at the end of this code line, i have tweaked it and mixed a bit with it but so far i haven't solved it.

```
 strSQL="INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES " + "(" + id + ",'" + rname + "','" + rfn + "','" + rmn + ")";
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is just aside your question but You should (seriously) have a look at what is SQL Injection and how to avoid it.

Comment: That why [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is used.

Comment: Yea i know im used with doing it in php, though this is just a school assignment so im not going to bother making it sql injection safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed several `'` signs. (not only in the end, but before and after the `id`)

```
strSQL="INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES " + "('" + id + "','" + rname + "','" + rfn + "','" + rmn + "')";
```

*Not related to the question*, but **strongly** related to the proper creation of queries in Java:

You should avoid constructing queries with String contatenation. Instead, use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) parameters. For example, you query would look like this:

```
strSQL="INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (?, ? , ? , ?)";
```

Comment: if the id is a number doesn't need the quote

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a quote at the end

```
+ rmn + " )";
         ^---------here
```

But actually you should rather use [*Prepared Statements*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no field name specified.write like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(val1, vale2);
```

Check url:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: i dont need to specify them in java.

Comment: @Looptech: my bad than. Thanks for bringing up.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi : if you are entering all the columns in the values , then you don't need to specify column names

Comment: @Looptech : where it says in java that you don't need to specify column names in java.